# Как предотвратить бесконечные вызовы функции в хуке useEffect?

Tags: reactjs

Есть состояние:

```js
const [opNames, setOpNames] = useState(
        props.brand.map((item) => {
            return { checked: false, name: item, id: item };
        })
    );
```

В пропсе бренд содержится массив, который парсится в объект. Мне нужно его обновить с помощью хука useEffect, но такой вариант:

```js
useEffect(() => {
            setOpNames(props.brand.map((item) => {
                return {checked: false, name: item, id: item};
            }));
    });
```

или оборачивание в функцию приводят к бесконечным вызовам. Как сделать так, чтобы состояние обновлялось только 1 раз?

P.s. - Попробовал сделать вот так:

```js
useEffect(() => {
            function newData () {
                let brand = props.brand;
                setOpNames(brand.map((item) => {
                    return {checked: false, name: item, id: item};
                }));
            }
            newData();
    }, [props.brand]);
```

Но получаю страшные высыпания в консоли, значения которых не понимаю:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хоть по факту все и работает, я бы предпочел это убрать.

Answer (score 0):

Ну ошибка не связана с хуком, если вам нужно отслеживать brend, передавайте вторым параметром в useEffect [props.brand]. Если надо просто один раз выполнить при монтаже компонента передайте пустой массив [].

Скорее у вас тут бардак

setOpNames(props.brand.map((item) => {
return {checked: false, name: item, id: item};
}));

Comment: Я там добавил дополнение на эту тему, получаю ворох алярмов в консоли, хотя все вроде как работает. В выражении точно проблем нет, ибо оно то же самое в состоянии прописано и пока я его не использую в эффекте проблем нет.

Comment: setOpNames(props.brand.map((item) => { return {checked: false, name: item.name, id: item.id}; }));  наверно как то так надо

Comment: и если делаете useEffect, то useState надо делать так const [opNames, setOpNames] = useState([]);

Comment: Так у меня по сути так и написано. Переменную только просто так написал, но потом убрал и вынес функцию за эффект. Сейчас все выглядит так: function newData () {
        setOpNames(props.brand.map((item) => {
            return {checked: false, name: item, id: item};
        }));
    }

    useEffect(() => {
            newData();
    }, [props.brand]);

Comment: item это строка?

Comment: Да, props.brand это массив, который парсится на строки, в финале получаем объект в состоянии opNames.